# TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'searchParams' of 'param' as it is undefined. in Nextjs

Tags: next.js

I want to fetch the data by using a async function (`await fetch()`) at request time in Nextjs. Since I need to use `await`, I added `async` into `export default function Page`:

My page.tsx:

```js
"use client"

export default function Page({
  searchParams,
}: {
  searchParams: SearchParams;
}) {
  const selectedMatch = searchParams.data || "[]";
...
```

However, I got:

```
TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'searchParams' of 'param' as it is undefined.
```

If I remove the `async` and `await fetch`, that's fine.
If I couldn't fetch the data by changing the function to asynchronous, how can I fix it?

Comment: Can you elaborate more? Is this `Model` a `page.tsx`? And what's that `param` mentioned in the error that is not visible in your code snippet?